# Jquery bring up date picker from text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

http://offline.raileisure.com/

I need to be able to bring up the datepicker from the text field as well as the little icon..

Any ideas ?

Thanks Lee

Comment: isn't this the default behavior?

Comment: Why are you adding the javascript libraries in the middle of the html and not inside the <head>? also you have other elements outside the <head> that belong there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
$('#bydate').datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
```

to

```
$('#bydate').datepicker({
        showOn: "both",
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's datepicker?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a different plugin, I suggest http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

Answer (score 0):

[Add a onclick handler](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to show the calendar with Jquery UI.

Answer (score 0):

Just looked at the site, you need to bind a click event to your image and then use the show method for the datepicker:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-trigger").click(function(){
    $(".hasDatepicker").datepicker("show");
});
```